# sql server clean up before migration

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-migration

I have to migrate two database from sql 2012 to 2016… I know both dbs have hundreds of SP rarely executed, tables not used, and I also suspect some jobs that touch tables on that DB are useless…I want to clean it before the migration.

What is the most professional approach? I know I could just rename everything and if nobody complains I can just delete stuff, but, if I rename tables maybe jobs start failing, so I think they may be important, but maybe nobody cares about those jobs.

Basically I do not know how to assess this. I am looking for a list of steps or a process, but cannot find it.

Comment: If I were you I would present two scenarios to the decision makers.  One, migrate as is and two do a cleanup first.  Try to estimate both efforts and explain the benefits of doing a cleanup.  Basically, in my opinion, the professional approach is to present as much information as possible, make a recommendation and ultimately do what the 'bosses' tell you to do.

Comment: Searching for applications, especially rarely used ones, and analyzing their source code may reveal some of what is used. Note that many systems have monthly, quarterly and annual processes. They may be based on calendar, fiscal, lunar or lunatic cycles. Be vewwy careful. And take good care of the _permanent backup_ that you create before you release the [Killer Rabbit of Caerbannog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbit_of_Caerbannog).

Comment: As per the two earlier comments, this kind of work is anything but simple. How many resources (time, people, money) are being dedicated to this project? If (as implied by the way you ask) it’s just you in your spare time, you could maybe target blatant junk (rename, then rename back if necessary), but otherwise don’t waste your time. (If there’s a serious commitment, mention this as of the question.)